# how to save retrieved values into pdf file in android application

Tags: android

I have retrieved some values in the application and I able to view in `ListView` or `TextView`. But same value can able to store or view in PDFs, word,Excel any possibilities there.
If there please Explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this can help...

```
public void appendLog(String text)
{       
   File logFile = new File("sdcard/log.txt");
   if (!logFile.exists())
   {
      try
      {
         logFile.createNewFile();
      } 
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   try
   {
      //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
      BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
      buf.append(text);
      buf.newLine();
      buf.close();
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Don't forget to add permission for writing_external_storage in Manifest!

Comment: thank you MDMAlik.....it work exactly

Comment: @Boopathi please do accept as the answer